# How to evaluate each file in folder with Batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, imagemagick, nested-loops

I'm using imagemagick in my batch script to evaluate a folder of jpg and png files. I want to check the print size of each image, and if it meets the criteria I specified, then output to a text file. My code is not working how i would like. It will output all of the data to the text file, but only if every image in the folder meets the criteria for correct size. I want it to evaluate each individual image. Currently, if there is 1 image not within the criteria, then nothing is written to the text file.

```
@echo off

REM %f - filename
REM %[size] - original size of image
REM %W - page width
REM %[resolution.x] - X density (resolution) without units
REM %H - page height
REM %[resolution.y] - Y density (resolution) without units
REM \n - newline
REM 1 in = 0.393701 cm - for PNG cm to in conversion

set output="C:\Documents and Settings\mfishm000\Desktop\Image_size.txt"

echo File_name:Size:Width:Height > %output%

REM set width as variable
FOR /F %%x IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:W/resolution.x]" *.jpg') DO SET width=%%x
FOR /F %%x IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:W/resolution.x*0.393701]" *.png') DO SET width=%%x

REM set height as variable
FOR /F %%y IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:H/resolution.y]" *.jpg') DO SET height=%%y 
FOR /F %%y IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:H/resolution.y*0.393701]" *.png') DO SET height=%%y

REM check if width is less than 8.67 and height is less than 11.22. If yes then output them to txt file
IF %width% LSS 8.67 (
    IF %height% LSS 11.22 (
        identify -format "%%f:%%[size]:%%[fx:W/resolution.x]:%%[fx:H/resolution.y]\n" *.jpg >> %output%
        identify -format "%%f:%%[size]:%%[fx:W/resolution.x*0.393701]:%%[fx:H/resolution.y*0.393701]\n" *.png >> %output%
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the problem is you need to process each file individually. Seems like you end up with only one width/height value of the last file processed.  Haven't tested, but this should work.

```
    @ECHO OFF

    REM %f - filename
    REM %[size] - original size of image
    REM %W - page width
    REM %[resolution.x] - X density (resolution) without units
    REM %H - page height
    REM %[resolution.y] - Y density (resolution) without units
    REM \n - newline
    REM 1 in = 0.393701 cm - for PNG cm to in conversion

    set output="C:\Documents and Settings\mfishm000\Desktop\Image_size.txt"

    echo File_name:Size:Width:Height > %output%


    for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^| find ".jpg"') do call :processA "%%~a"
    for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^| find ".png"') do call :processB "%%~a"

    exit /B

    :processA
        FOR /F %%x IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:W/resolution.x]" %1') DO SET width=%%x
        FOR /F %%y IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:H/resolution.y]" %1') DO SET height=%%y
        IF %width% LSS 8.67 (
            IF %height% LSS 11.22 (
                identify -format "%%f:%%[size]:%%[fx:W/resolution.x]:%%[fx:H/resolution.y]\n" %1 >> %output%
            )
        )
    goto:eof

    :processB
        FOR /F %%x IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:W/resolution.x*0.393701]" %1') DO SET width=%%x
        FOR /F %%y IN ('identify -format "%%[fx:H/resolution.y*0.393701]" %1') DO SET height=%%y
        IF %width% LSS 8.67 (
            IF %height% LSS 11.22 (
                identify -format "%%f:%%[size]:%%[fx:W/resolution.x*0.393701]:%%[fx:H/resolution.y*0.393701]\n" %1 >> %output%
            )
        )
    goto:eof
```